# How to redirect to another project in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I am developing `mvc` application. The structure of the application is same as [This Link.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526827/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-Multilingual-Site-Skeleton)

Now I want to add some modules in different projects. Like, `AdminModule`, `BookingModule` and so on. When user logs in to the system, he will redirected to the project he is authorized and assigned to. User can be assigned to more than one project.

So now the question is, how the user can be redirected to the project he is assigned? And what if more than one projects are assigned to him? Is this architecture is good for what I want to do? You can also suggest me any other architecture. One more thing, I am using code first and unit of work approach. So the `models` and `repositories` would be in different project. The solution would look like below.

[image: here is the image.]

Answer (score 0):

If I think I know what you are doing, I've tried this and it works
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356883

I just had to also ensure the built-in permissions syntax allowed the specific users to enter (i.e AuthorizeUser attribute)