# How do I href to an MVC page from an ASP.NET page in another project in the same solution

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio C# solution with an ASP.NET web forms project.  I am adding another project developed separately, done as MVC.  I have added the MVC project to the existing solution, alongside the ASP.NET project.  In the web forms project, there is a home page with links to various tools (otehr web forms pages).  I want to add a link that will point to the Home controller in the MVC project, but I cannot figure out how to write the href tag.  It seems like I am missing something very basic here, but after Googling awhile I could only find how to call URLs from MVC using Razor and so on, not the other way around.  Even if I hard-code a URL, such as href="http://localhost:59502/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", it does not work, and I obviously don't want to hardcode a domain.  But if I just put "/Home/" that gives an error as well.  How do I link to an MVC page in the same solution but a different project?

Comment: Hey Pete, Have a look at this answer and see if it helps Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356831/mvc-redirect-from-one-project-to-another-in-one-solution

Comment: Yes, excellent, that helped me understand what I was missing.  I never knew that I could start two projects at once in the same solution.  Once I did that, and I could see the different localhost ports, it clicked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Happy to Help..